# Decomposition of an arbitrary 1-qubit gate into a specific gateset

Tags: gate-synthesis

Any 1-qubit special gate can be decomposed into a sequence of rotation gates ($R_z$, $R_y$ and $R_z$). This allows us to have the general 1-qubit special gate in matrix form:

$$
U\left(\theta,\phi,\lambda\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{-i(\phi+\lambda)}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -e^{-i(\phi-\lambda)}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\
e^{i(\phi-\lambda)}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & e^{i(\phi+\lambda)}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{array}\right)
$$

If given $U\left(\theta,\phi,\lambda\right)$, how do I decompose it into any arbitrary set of gates such as rotation gates, pauli gates, etc?

To make the question more concrete, here is my current situation: for my project, I am giving users the ability to apply $U\left(\theta,\phi,\lambda\right)$ for specific values of $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\lambda$ to qubits.
But I am targeting real machines that only offer specific gates. For instance, the Rigetti Agave quantum processor only offers $R_z$, $R_x\left(k\pi/2\right)$ and $CZ$ as primitive gates.
**One can think of any $U\left(\theta,\phi,\lambda\right)$ as an intermediate form that needs to be transformed into a sequence of whatever is the native gateset of the target quantum processor.**

Now, in that spirit, how do I transform any $U\left(\theta,\phi,\lambda\right)$ into say $R_z$ and $R_x\left(k\pi/2\right)$? Let us ignore $CZ$ since it is a 2-qubit gate.

Note: I'm writing a compiler so an algorithm and reference papers or book chapters that solve this exact problems are more than welcome!

Comment: You mention cZ which is a two-qubit gate. Therefore, you also want deocmpositions that include auxiliary qubits?

Comment: @user1271772 Shoot, I glossed over that. I have edited the question to reflect your comment. Thanks.

Comment: If we no longer have Ry, then can we still decompose any general U without auxiliary qubits and things like cZ?

Comment: @user1271772 No, we can't. I will edit my question after thinking more about it so that it can be answered accurately. Once again, thanks for your attention to details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Exact decomposition for your particular gate set

Given the range of $R_x$ gates available to you together with arbitrary $R_z$ gates, you should be able to find an easy decomposition of arbitrary $R_y$ gates (*i.e.* as a product of three of your elementary gates). Then using simple techniques — similar to the exercises of Chapter 4 in Nielsen & Chuang — you can show that you can exactly realise any single-qubit unitary operator that you like, using at most five of your gates.

#### The general problem of approximate decomposition for finite gate-sets

In general, it may not be possible to decompose a single-qubit gate exactly, as a product of some other single-qubit gates. This is true even of 'universal' gate sets such as Hadamard+T, consisting of the gates
$$
H = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \!&\! \phantom-1 \\ 1 \!&\! -1 \end{bmatrix},
\qquad
T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \!\mathrm{e}^{\pi i \!\:/ 4}\! \end{bmatrix},
$$
which of course can only generate a countably infinite subgroup of the continuum of single-qubit unitaries. The sense in which they are 'universal' is that this subgroup is *dense* in the single-qubit unitaries, so that any single-qubit unitary can be approximated as closely as you like by some product of *H* and *T* gates, which is all that we really need to solve problems with **bounded error** on quantum computers. So it makes sense to me, practically speaking, to interpret your question as asking:

> **Question.**  For a given single-qubit unitary $U$, how can you generate some approximating unitary $V$ (such that $\lVert U - V \rVert < \varepsilon$, for some precision parameter $\varepsilon > 0$) from a set of unitary gates?

- The best-known work on these lines was by Solovay [unpublished] and Kitaev [[Russ. Math. Sure. **52** (1191–1249), 1997]](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1997v052n06ABEH002155/meta), and is known as the Solovay–Kitaev Theorem. The excellent review article by Dawson and Nielsen [[arXiv:quant-ph/0505030](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030)] would be a good place to read about this from an algorithms point of view: they give a detailed description of how you might realise such a decomposition, with improved run-time bounds on the original Theorem. This technique only works if the set of gates that you have is closed under inverses, however.
- For specific gate sets such as Clifford+T (of which Hadamard+T is
  essentially the single-qubit special case), it is possible to do much better than the Solovay–Kitaev Theorem proves for general (but closed under inverses) gate sets. As [Alan Geller](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4265/alan-geller) points out in the comments, for the specific sets of Clifford+T, Clifford+(Z<sup>1/6</sup>) or "Clifford+$\pi$/12" gates, and "Fibonacci" or "V"  gates, the techniques developed by Kliuchnikov, Bocharov, Roetteler, and
  Yard [[arXiv:1510.03888](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03888)]
  allow you to obtain better asymptotically optimal $O(\log(1/\varepsilon))$ decompositions, and in $O(\mathrm{polylog}(1/\varepsilon))$ time, though depending in on a number theoretic conjecture in this case.

Comment: Yes, your rephrased question is more or less what I seek. I am going to review the references you link to and see if I can put them to use. I had already read up on the Solovay-Kitaev theorem but was unable to make an algorithm out of it but it appears the Nielsen paper will come in handy.
**Note:** in your rephrased question, you repeat _can_ twice.

Comment: A more up-to-date paper (2015) from Vadym and collaborators is https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03888.

Comment: @AlanGeller: Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer to point to that!